# Plotly Python: Add alpha to predefined color

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm following [this example](https://plotly.com/python/continuous-error-bars/) from the Plotly documentation but I'm trying to set the color of the confidence region as the same chosen color for the line but with added transparency (alpha), unlike the docs example in which the fill color is defined manually. Is there a way to do it?

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do. In the function defined in the snippet, ideally I would be able to set `color` in any way acceptable by Plotly (e.g. `color="red"`, or `color="rgb(31, 119, 180)"`) and have alpha added for the fill.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/wind_speed_laurel_nebraska.csv')

def gen_plot_ci(x, y, y_lo, y_hi, color):
    fig = go.Figure([
        go.Scatter(
            name='Measurement',
            x=x,
            y=y,
            mode='lines',
            line=dict(color=color),  # <-- Using the `color` argument for the line
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            name='Upper Bound',
            x=x,
            y=y_hi,
            mode='lines',
            marker=dict(color="#000"),
            line=dict(width=0),
            showlegend=False
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            name='Lower Bound',
            x=x,
            y=y_lo,
            marker=dict(color="#444"),
            line=dict(width=0),
            mode='lines',
            fillcolor='rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.3)',  # <-- Here I'd like to use the `color` argument and just add alpha
            fill='tonexty',
            showlegend=False
        )
    ])
    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis_title='Wind speed (m/s)',
        title='Continuous, variable value error bars',
        hovermode="x"
    )
    fig.show()

gen_plot_ci(
    df['Time'],
    df['10 Min Sampled Avg'],
    df['10 Min Sampled Avg']-df['10 Min Std Dev'],
    df['10 Min Sampled Avg']+df['10 Min Std Dev'],
    color='rgb(31, 119, 180)',
)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to use `color="#444"` again but with added transparency?

Comment: Not the `color="#444"`, that's related to the marker and will not be displayed because of the zero line width (`line=dict(width=0)`). I'd like to use the color passed in the `color` argument from my function `gen_plot_ci()`, but with added alpha

Comment: I see. I will look into that.

Comment: How did the latest suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you use an `rgb`color like `color="rgb(31, 119, 180)")` for the initial line color,  we're really just manipulating strings here.
So after setting up your figure in you function definition, just include the following before you call `fig.show()`

```
fig.data[2].fillcolor = 'rgba' + fig.data[0].line.color[3:-1]  + ', ' + str(transparency) + ')'
```

And remeber to define `transparency = 0.2` or another number somewhere in your code or as an argument in your function.

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
# from PIL import ImageColor

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/wind_speed_laurel_nebraska.csv')

transparency = 0.2

def gen_plot_ci(x, y, y_lo, y_hi, color):
#     global fig
    fig = go.Figure([
        go.Scatter(
            name='Measurement',
            x=x,
            y=y,
            mode='lines',
            line=dict(color=color),  # <-- Using the `color` argument for the line
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            name='Upper Bound',
            x=x,
            y=y_hi,
            mode='lines',
            marker=dict(color="#000"),
            line=dict(width=0),
            showlegend=False
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            name='Lower Bound',
            x=x,
            y=y_lo,
            marker=dict(color="#444"),
            line=dict(width=0),
            mode='lines',
            fillcolor='rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.3)',  # <-- Here I'd like to use the `color` argument and just add alpha
#             fillcolor = 'rgba' + str(tuple(list(ImageColor.getcolor("#444", "RGB")) + [transparency])),
#             fillcolor = 'rgba' + fig.data[0].line.color[3:-1]  + ', ' + str(transparency) + ')',
            fill='tonexty',
            showlegend=False
        )
    ])
    
    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis_title='Wind speed (m/s)',
        title='Continuous, variable value error bars',
        hovermode="x"
    )
    fig.data[2].fillcolor = 'rgba' + fig.data[0].line.color[3:-1]  + ', ' + str(transparency) + ')'
    fig.show()

gen_plot_ci(
    df['Time'],
    df['10 Min Sampled Avg'],
    df['10 Min Sampled Avg']-df['10 Min Std Dev'],
    df['10 Min Sampled Avg']+df['10 Min Std Dev'],
    color='rgb(31, 119, 180)',
)
```